# wrong output in python function code

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have `rootFile = root.json` file which content is

```
{
  "tests":[
    {
      "test":"test1",
      "url":"url1"
    },
    {
      "test":"test2",
      "url":"url2"
    },
    {
      "test":"test3",
      "url":"url3"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I have python function to which I am giving string params to run

```
def check(params):
    runId=time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        outputFile=Path(""+runId+".txt")
    with open (rootFile) as rj:
        data=json.load(rj)
    for param in params:
        for t in data['tests']:
            if t['test'] == param:
                urlToUse=t['url']
                testrun(param, urlToUse, runId)
            else:
                nonExistingTest="Test "+param+" Doesn't exist \n"
                if not outputFile.exists():
                    with open(outputFile,"a") as noSuchTest:
                        noSuchTest.write("Test "+param+" Doesn't exist \n")
                elif not nonExistingTest in open(outputFile).read():
                    with open(outputFile,"a") as noSuchTest:
                        noSuchTest.write("Test "+param+" Doesn't exist \n")
    with open(outputFile,"r") as pf:
        message=pf.read()
        slackResponse(message)
```

when my params is "test1 test2 test3" which exist in root.json file I am getting such response

```
Test test1 passed #this response comes from testrun() function
Test test1 Doesn't exist

Test test2 Doesn't exist
Test test2 passed  #this response comes from testrun() function

Test test3 Doesn't exist
Test test3 passed  #this response comes from testrun() function
```

But when I am giving non existing params the output is correct. e.g

```
Test test4 Doesn't exist
Test test5 Doesn't exist
Test test6 Doesn't exist
Test test7 Doesn't exist
```

Can't understand why it's sending doesn't exist when it's actually exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing each parameter passed with the function call to every item of the `tests` array loaded from the json file, starting the corresponding test on equivalence, and echoing a message saying that such a test does not exist otherwise.
Because this comparison will only have a positive result once per parameter, but will be checked as many times as there are tests specified in `root.json` for each parameter, there will be a lot of lines in the output indicating that a particular parameter doesn't match a particular test specified in `root.json`.

You'll need some way to leave the loop once you've found the `root.json` entry that is being adressed by the current parameter. I'd recommend either changing the data structure assigned to `tests` in `root.json` from an array to an object, with the test names as keys and their urls as values, or somehow filter the list of possible tests that you compare the current parameter with.

Consider changing everything inside `for param in params:` into the following:

```
matching_tests = [t for t in data['tests'] if t['test'] == param]
if len(matching_tests) > 0:
    for t in matching_tests:
        urlToUse=t['url']
        testrun(param, urlToUse, runId)
else:
    nonExistingTest="Test "+param+" Doesn't exist \n"
    [...]
```

That way, the message saying that there is not test matching a given parameter will only be echoed at most once.